# Java operator precedence and assignments

Tags: java, operators, variable-assignment, operator-precedence

I just strugle to understand something about java operator precedence and assignments. Here the example:

```
int a = 10, b = 20;

int c = a + (a = b) * 0;
```

Why is the result `c = 10`? This means that for the first `a` in the calculation the old value of `a` is used. But the assigment in `( )` should have a higher precedence than the addition. Why isn't it done first?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but please, never write code like this in a real-world project.

Comment: The addition is evaluated left-to-right, I believe. By the time we evaluate `(a=b)` the left operand was already evaluated and locked in.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Of course. It's from an "tricky code questions" example.

Comment: @Arkadiy But doesn't the operator precedence change excactly that? So the order in which operands are evaluated.

Comment: Operator precedence decides whether it's `(a+b)*0` or `a+(b*0)`. The order of execution is not affected.